# run a batch file that is present in remote machine

Tags: java

The above code works fine if the batch file is present in local machine.
I need to run the batch file that is present in the remote machine from the above code.

```
class Visuals {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            String command = "cmd /C start C:/Visuals/VisualTimeSeries081308Ratnesh/VisualTimeSeries081308Ratnesh/bat/demo/StartVisTsDataCenterMySql-log.bat";
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec(command);
            //pr.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I develop connection with the remote machine?  I just have the IP address of the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the Folder containing the batch file as a Public Share and then use that address of the batch file like "\ComputerName\ShareName\BatchFile", you can access the batch file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to export your Visuals class to an RMI server, and then invoke the method that executes the batch file remotely from a remote client.

Take a look at the [Sun RMI Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/rmi/index.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AT command](http://www.ss64.com/nt/at.html). According to its documentation:

> The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
>   a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
>   the AT command.

So you might be able to do something like:

```
AT \\123.123.123.123 17:00 cmd /c "C:\test.bat"
```

If you set the time you want to run it at approximately the current time, your script will run.

Edit: this is what you would run from the command-line. You should put this in your command string.

Answer (score 0):

To update my previous answer, you really need to look at the documentation otherwise it is unlikely you will understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried AT and it throws a access denied error.

This is also tricky in the sense that it schedules the remote machine to run a task at the specified time.

If the machine clocks are not in synch this could cause trouble.

There should be other alternatives available.

THanks,
Manglu